# The code is written in C# and I want to drag any object in unity 3D using mouse. I have tried many things but not found any reasonable solution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Drag: MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject getTarget;
    bool isMouseDragging;

    Vector3 offsetValue;
    Vector3 positionOfScreen;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
           RaycastHit hitInfo;
           getTarget = ReturnClickedObject(out hitInfo);

           if (getTarget != null)
           {
               isMouseDragging = true;
               //Converting world position to screen position.
               positionOfScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint 
                              (getTarget.transform.position);
               offsetValue = getTarget.transform.position - Camera.main.Screen 
                         ToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,   
                         Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
             isMouseDragging = false;
        }

        if (isMouseDragging)
        {
              Vector3 currentScreenSpace = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z);
              Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (currentScreenSpace) + offsetValue;
              getTarget.transform.position = currentPosition;
        }
   }

   GameObject ReturnClickedObject(out RaycastHit hit)
   {
       GameObject target = null;
       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
       if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit))
       {
        target = hit.collider.gameObject;
       }
       return target;
      }

}
```

the code is about unity 3D... i want to drag  any 3D object(cube, sphere etc.) using Mouse... i create the object from hierarchy and apply the script on that object that i want to drag..... when i run that the object is not selected and not dragged........... i have checked many sites but not found any reasonable solution.

Comment: Most likely it is because your `ReturnClickedObject` function returns `null` Add  `Debug.Log("Target is hit")` line to your if in the function and check if it is displayed in console.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, unity's IDragHandler could solve your problem.

This interface can be used to receive a DragEvent. For this you have to implement in your class the method `void OnDrag (PointerEventData data)`. To respond to the start of an OnDrag event, you can implement the IDragStart interface using the void `OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)` method. At the end you can also react with the IDragEnd interface and the method `void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventDat)`.

For the exact use of the IDragHandler you can look in the Unity documentation. Here is the link:

[IDragHandler interface in UnityEngine.EventSystems](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html)

I hope that can help you.

Comment: @Zoe Thanks, I have improved the post. I hope it is better now